# Publish-Repository read NuGet API key from NuGet config

Tags: powershell, nuget

I want to publish a module to `PowerShellGallery`. I already created an API key and can manually publish my module via:

```
Publish-Module -Name MyModule -NuGetApiKey MyApiKey -Repository PSGallery
```

This works fine. I want to automate publishing, therefore I need to get rid of the `-NuGetApiKey` parameter. Is it possible to store the API key in a user specific config file? I already registered the API key via `nuget setapikey ...`, but it seems that `Publish-Module` doesn't care about `Nuget.config` file.

thx